# how to get item number in view pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

how to get current  item no in viewpager.

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup paramView, int paramInt) {


        int itemno1= getItem(pager.getCurrentItem());
                   int itemno2= getItem(paramInt);

        Toast.makeText(context, "postition"+itemno1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "postition"+itemno2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }
```

but this methods are not working properly.when ever i swipe front and back it gives the wrong item no..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener` on your viewpager.

Some thing like this-

```
myViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
              // here you will get the position of selected page
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
ViewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

or

```
pageListener = new PageListener();
ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);
```

you have to put a page change listener for your viewPager. There is no method on viewPager to get the current page.

```
private int currentPage;

    private static class PageListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener{
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.i(TAG, "page selected " + position);
                   currentPage = position;
        }
    }
```